# Cross Origin Read Blocking (CORB) when accessing branch API

Tags: branch.io, cross-origin-read-blocking

I receive the following error when implementing Branch

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
https://branch.io/ with MIME type text/html. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is caused due to content security policy violations. Please try passing a nonce value to protect against this.

`branch.init(YOUR_BRANCH_KEY, {'nonce': 'GENERATED_NONCE_VALUE' });`

Comment: I've applied a 10 character nonce, but am still getting the CORB error. `window.branch.init(props.key, {nonce: randomString(10) });`

Comment: Can you please make sure you generate a dynamic nonce value, and include that value as a script-src and style-src exception within your Content Security Policy? You should pass that same value to branch.init(). 


branch.init(YOUR_BRANCH_KEY, {'nonce': 'GENERATED_NONCE_VALUE' });

Comment: By dynamic do you mean that the nonce value should be unique to the users session, and that it should change if the user refreshes the page?  Also how should the nonce be included in my content security policy exceptions? Does it matter how long the string is?  if there is documentation available please let me know as I would love to save you the time to answer all these questions

Comment: Please reference this link-> https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/content-security-policy/